# Having Trouble Solving this System of ODEs

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am having trouble finding any solution to this ODE:

```
ρ = 1.225;
b = 47.5;
Sw = 290;
AR = b^2/Sw;
m = 176000; g=9.81; W=m*g;

Lclimb = 1/2 ρ*(Vclimb[t])^2*Sw*CLfun;
Dclimb = 1/2 ρ*(Vclimb[t])^2*Sw (f/Sw + CLfun^2/(π*e*AR));
Tclimb = 2*(At*(Vclimb[t])^2 + Bt*Vclimb[t] + Ct);
Eqn1 = (Tclimb - Dclimb - W*Sin[θ[t]])/m == D[Vclimb[t], t];
Eqn2 = (Lclimb - W*Cos[θ[t]])/(m*Vclimb[t]) == D[θ[t], t];
DSolve[{Eqn1, Eqn2, Vclimb[0]==75, θ[0]==3 Degree}, {Vclimb, θ}, t]
```

I would be fine with NDSolve too, I just can't get this to evaluate to anything and want to know if I am doing anything wrong syntax wise or in my method.

Comment: If you change your code to use lowerCaseFirstLetter for symbols and variables, I'll try to help. I just can't look at user variables which uses UpperCaseFirstLetter.

Comment: @Nasser His camel has overturned

Comment: @J.W.Perry {Vclimb and θ} are the functions he's solving for

Answer (score 4):

With `NDSolve[]`, after giving values for all your constants:

```
ρ = 1.225;
b = 47.5;
Sw = 290;
AR = b^2/Sw;
m = 176000; g = 9.81; W = m*g;
CLfun = 1; f = 1; e = 1; At = 1; Bt = 1; Ct = 1;

Lclimb = 1/2 ρ*(Vclimb[t])^2*Sw*CLfun;
Dclimb = 1/2 ρ*(Vclimb[t])^2*Sw (f/Sw + CLfun^2/(π*e*AR));
Tclimb = 2*(At*(Vclimb[t])^2 + Bt*Vclimb[t] + Ct);
Eqn1 = (Tclimb - Dclimb - W*Sin[θ[t]])/m == D[Vclimb[t], t];
Eqn2 = (Lclimb - W*Cos[θ[t]])/(m*Vclimb[t]) ==  D[θ[t], t];

s = NDSolve[{Eqn1, Eqn2, Vclimb[0] == 75, θ[0] == 3 Degree}, {Vclimb, θ}, {t,  0, 10}]
Plot[{Vclimb[t], 100 (θ[t] + 1)} /. s, {t, 0, 10}, Evaluated -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]